# An error MSB3086 occurs while building the project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Please help when building a project the following error occurs.
Please tell me how to solve.

```
Error   MSB3086 Task could not find "al.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\NETFXSDK\4.8\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed    project1.neuralVs   D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    3747
```

Comment: Where is `al.exe` located? The task can't find it.

Comment: The fact is that I do not know where it should be.

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see `Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed`

You should reinstall Windows SDK from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/)

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602414/error-could-not-find-al-exe-using-sdktoolspath).